# Is the Xcode Memory Report showing total bytes or live/persistent bytes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory, instruments

Is the Xcode Memory Report showing total bytes or live/persistent bytes?

My memory report shows me ~70 mb of memory usage but my allocations instrument shows me ~4.5 mb persistent bytes when running the same code.

Comment: That is a quick view but to get better information run the profiler: Xcode menu, Product, Profile.

Comment: Yep. I am using that profile as the basis for my question on the quick view.